# How to console log in remix IDE

Tags: debugging, solidity, remix

I am trying to console and debug the code or solidity

I am using https://remix.ethereum.org/

Answer (score 17):

```
// remix supports hardhat console.log;

// 1st import as follows
import "hardhat/console.sol";

// then to log use:
console.log("log 1")
```

Comment: in remix desktop i dont see any trace... only in my hardhat terminal